# My first camera

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-recommendation

I am new to photography and even cameras for that matter. I like to travel, especially to exotic places in Asia and South America, where often one doesn't have the luxury of artificial lighting. I am looking to buy my first camera. One that would help me capture good images in my travels (Good ones, if not extraordinary), and I want to be able to take good ones even in the dark. Plus, I'd like to go for one which will will not go obsolete in a year like mobile phones do.

Also, my budget isn't greater than $500. :P

Does anyone have a suggestion? :)

Comment: Please read [Q&A Is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) to see why you haven't had a lot of response (and negative response really). I think you can recover this question, which is why I haven't closed it, by asking it a little different. Instead of asking "what camera" you may want to ask what features will help achieve your goal. Armed with that, you can shop with more confidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a right or wrong answer for this, though at your price range you are looking at either a nice point and shoot or a bare bones DSLR model.  The point and shoot will probably give you more features up front, but the DSLR will allow you to upgrade lenses in the future to improve the quality of photos you can take and you could eventually upgrade your camera body if you wanted to really improve.

The main advantage of the DSLR would be superior image quality and the ability to easily upgrade incrementally.  The disadvantage is size and portability.  The point and shoot on the other hand would be very portable, which sounds like it would matter for your purposes, but you wouldn't be able to upgrade it.  You'd just have to buy a new camera when you want to move up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You've taken enough time to detail it. I appreciate that. :) Though portability is a very real issue, I think I'm kinda inclining toward the DSLR suggestion, through your points, because of the scope in improvement and scalability. Your answer definitely deserves a vote. :)

Comment: Also, if it's not too much, could you suggest a few potential models in either category? (Brand doesn't matter) :)

Comment: Unfortunately, to try and keep things generic and timeless, we try to avoid giving exact model recommendations (unless it is comparing two specific models) since models change fairly frequently.  If you look at the major manufacturers however, it's pretty easy to find their entry level models.  Canon and Nikon are the two biggest brands by far. Sony, Pentax and Olympus are some of the popular smaller brands.  Canon's DSLR line is the EOS line and within that line Rebel cameras are typically the entry level models.